# Visual Studio C# view output

Tags: c#

Working through a string deduplicating and finding that when I rebuild and run the console closes and I don't see what the string is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StringPrintDuplicates
{
class Program
{
    public static void DedupString(List<string> duplicatesString)
    {
        List<string> distinctList = duplicatesString.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach(string deduped in distinctList) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",deduped);
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("t");
        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("l");
        list.Add("k");
        list.Add("j");
        list.Add("l");
        list.Add("l");
        list.Add("k");
        list.Add("k");
        list.Add("s");
        list.Add("s");
        list.Add("h");
        list.Add("h");
        list.Add("o");
        list.Add("e");
        Console.WriteLine("The input is: {0} ", list.ToString());
        DedupString(list);
    }
   }
 }
```

When I run this I don't get an errors and the output should be the letters that are duplicated in the list. I am using 2019 and configured to stop console when debugging and also not use "Just my code" but I see nothing. This should return "lksh".

Comment: So you're looking for a list of the strings where there's more than one occurrence? That's not what distinct does - it returs the elements in the sequence, **ignoring** duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems I see right after I noticed the code.

1. `Distinct()` is a keyword to remove all duplicates
2. Your `list.ToString()` will definitely not work, the reason why is that you want to concat all strings together. For this, you should use `Aggregate()`.

If you really want to return just those, that are duplicates, you want to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void DedupString(List<string> duplicatesString)
        {
            List<string> distinctList = duplicatesString.Distinct().ToList();
            foreach(string deduped in distinctList) {
                Console.Write("{0}",deduped);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static void DuplicitsOnly(List<string> duplicatesString)
        {
            var distinctList = duplicatesString.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            foreach(string deduped in distinctList) {
                Console.Write("{0}",deduped);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("t");
            list.Add("a");
            list.Add("l");
            list.Add("k");
            list.Add("j");
            list.Add("l");
            list.Add("l");
            list.Add("k");
            list.Add("k");
            list.Add("s");
            list.Add("s");
            list.Add("h");
            list.Add("h");
            list.Add("o");
            list.Add("e");
            Console.WriteLine("The input is: {0} ", list.Aggregate("", (x, y) => x + y));
            DedupString(list);
            DuplicitsOnly(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, about the Console closing ... I had a same problem ... at the right down corner, you should see "Application Output"... I dont know how to fix it for sure, but this was the way I found the console :) ( or just smash a ReadLine(); at the en of a file ... that one should work too )

Answer (score 1):

StyleZ and Chandru are correct - . As an aside, as of C#3, you can initialize your lists like this:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "t", "a", "l", "k", "j", "l", "l", "k", "k", "s", "s", "h", "h", "o", "e" };
```

This may be easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way (maybe simpler)
1) You can modify DedupString method like below for showing only duplicate entries:

```
    public static void DedupString(List<string> duplicatesString)
    {
        List<string> distinctList = duplicatesString.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (string deduped in distinctList)
        {                
            if(duplicatesString.FindAll(x => x.Equals(deduped)).Count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", deduped);
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Add `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of `Main()` to prevent console from closing. Only after pressing enter key, console will close.